# Change typeface in caption figure

Tags: floats, captions, bold, small-caps

It is possible to make the caption of a figure in CAPS (versalitas) typeface format? 
Like as image below. But I want to change only the 'FIGURE 1.1'. Descriptive text label that is invariant. That has not been answered in another post

I also want to ask if it

is possible to write in bold the test in CAPS format?

[image]
Code (false) right here for either case:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsthm}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{center}
  \fbox{\parbox[b]{.3\linewidth}{
    \begin{center}
     .......\\This is a figure\\*******
    \end{center} }
  }
  \end{center}

  \begin{center}
  \textsc{Figure 1.1:} Solution of $x^2\leq 4$
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: But I want to change only the 'FIGURE 1.1'. Descriptive text label that is invariant. That has not been answered in another post.

Comment: Please read the very good documentation of the `caption` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add some more details for the case of bold smallcaps.

Load the `caption` package:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=sc]{caption}
```

If you want small caps only for the figure environment:

```
 \usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=sc}
```

For bold smallcaps, you need a font that has such glyphs. Latin Modern doesn't but cm-super has. So if you use Computer Modern fonts,  writing in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bsc}{\textbf{\textsc{#1}\ #2}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=bsc}
```

should work.

Comment: \usepackage{caption}
           \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bsc}{\textbf{\textsc{#1}\ #2}}
           \captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=bsc}

makes text bold but not delete the caps format

Comment: Why a new format? It's enough to use `\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,sc}}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina this code produces bold text but format times. It removes the caps

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Well, I thought that, in case of using cm-super,  one _had_ to use \textbf{\textsc{...}} and it was only way to do so was \DeclareLabelFormat. Moreover if the main font is Latin Modern, one should also change the font family for cm-super – btw I'm unsure of how to do this; maybe \fontfamily{t1cm}\selectfont?

Comment: @mathsalomon: Does your version of times have bols smallcaps?

Comment: @mathsalomon No. If you are using a font that supports boldfaced small caps, my code produces the expected result.

Comment: @Bernard @GonzaloMedina : yes with `\usepackage{bold-extra}` I resolved.
Many thanks Bernard & Gonzalo